# Move multiple files to new directory preserving paths

Tags: bash, awk

I'd like to move a number of files out of the current directory to a new one while preserving their original paths (e.g. `example/app1/main.c` should be moved to `/newdir/example/app1/main.c`).

I created all of the necessary directories via. the following:

```
git ls-files --others | awk -F '/' '{print "/home/user/newdir/"$1"/"$2}' | xargs mkdir -p
```

But I'm not sure how to force `mv` to use the `git ls-files --others` directory paths in determining the new locations.

Answer (score 1):

One way I usually do this is with tar, since it's very good at preserving files.

```
tar -c -f - $(git ls-files --other) | tar -x -f - -C /newdir && git clean -df
```

Or something similar should be what you want.  The first tar creates a tar on stdout which is read by the second; the second extracts it to the destination.  Afterwards, we need to remove the files, hence the git clean.

Note that if you have many files, you can break up the first tar into two parts:

```
git ls-files > /tmp/files && tar -c -f - -T /tmp/files ...
```